# Вывод сообщений по хэштегу vk

Tags: vkontakte-api, hashtag

Планируется вывод на сайте отзывов из сообщений в *VK* по хэштегу.

Для этих целей нужно использовать метод *VK API* `newsfeed.search`?

Comment: Да, и неважно, по чему искать, по тексту или по хэштегу.

Answer (score 2):

> Для этих целей нужно использовать метод VK API `newsfeed.search`?

Да. Других вариантов-то и нет.

Comment: Спасибо, разобрался! Возник еще вопрос, немного не по теме но все же... Как обработать строку вырезав из нее все хеш теги? т.е нужно найти слова начинающиеся с # рассчитать длину до предстоящего пробела и вырезать его. Но как лучше это сделать не допру, можно на массив разбить и элементы содержание # удалять, либо прям из строки резать.. посоветуйте?

Comment: @IlyaKalashnikov, смотрите в сторону регулярных выражений и функциям по замене строки по регулярному выражению на языке, на котором пишете. Если будут проблемы - создайте новый вопрос, подробно описав желаемый результат и действия, которые вы предпринимали, пытаясь достичь его.

Answer (score 0):

Для этого используйте Streaming API - [Документация](https://vk.com/dev/streaming_api)